# What do $#, $1 and $2 mean?

Tags: linux, bash

My question is about a bash-programme, which is in this big book about programming a raspberry pi (bash, Python, C).

There is a sample programme to show how the *if* works in bash, but no matter how many times a read through the description of the programme, it just doesn't seem to explain properly what it does (I know it's too much to ask if I want a thorough bash tutorial in a 1000 pages book, and that's why I'm here)

So here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

if test $# -ne 2; then
    echo "You have to pass 2 arguments to the command"
    #argument / parameter, whatever you prefer
    exit 1
else
    echo "Argument 1: $1, argument 2: $2"
fi
```

I understand, that the `-ne 2` means: not equal to 2, so it checks if the `$#` is equal to 2, but I don't understand what it does (the `$#`). -> First question

In the `else` it prints the `$1` and `$2`, but I thought that `$variablename` would print the value of that variable. How can an integer be a variable? -> second question

And yes, I google'ed and didn't find anything of use (maybe didn't search enough?), which is exactly why I'm here.

I would appreciate any kind of help, be it a link to read it myself, or a short explanation.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This is also something readily available in man pages and static web pages you can search for.  Not sure this was ever worthy of a StackOverflow response.

Comment: If you're going to be using `bash`, I strongly recommend that you read the manual! In a terminal, `man bash` or [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.pdf), in a PDF file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `$#` refers to the number of parameters received at run time, not a specific parameter.  `$1` gets replaced by whatever was in location 1 on the command line when the script was executed.

Comment: Thank you very much! That helped.

Answer (score 2):

`$#` Denotes the number of command line arguments or positional parameters

`$1`and `$2` denote the first and second command line argument passed, respectively